# Error with SQL Server 2008 R2 Japanese (NVARCHAR) String Comparison?

Tags: sql-server, unicode, sql-server-2008-r2

## Problem

When I run the following query on SQL Server 2008 R2, two distinct japanese unicode strings are treated as being equal:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN N'食料' = N'食料ㇰ ㇱ ㇲ ㇳ'
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END;

--result: 1
```

I know that the kana following the kanji are half-width but since there are no similar full-width kana I wouldn't expect width sensitivity or kana sensitivity to matter. However, if the kana are replaced with full-width versions the comparison behaves as expected:

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN N'食料' = N'食料ク　シ　ス　ト'
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END;

--result: 0
```

## Attempted Solutions

This led me to think the issue might be related to my collation which is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`.

First, I tried `Latin1_General_CI_AS` in case it was a quirk of SQL Unicode comparison but that did not solve the issue.

Then, I figured I would use the most restrictive collation possible (all sensitivities on) but other collations including `Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS` and `Japanese_Unicode_CS_AS_KS_WS` did not change the result when using half-width trailing kana (all correctly identified the difference with full-width trailing kana).

To verify that the strings are different at a byte level, I ran the query with half-width trailing kana after removing the `N`(nvarchar) designation for the strings and verified it returns the expected result of `0`.

## Questions

What is going on here? Am I simply not trying the right collation? Is this an error in SQL Server 2008 R2? Is there something specific about Japanese Unicode that I am not aware of? Why would the presence of half-width trailing kana not make these strings different?

PS I don't know Japanese so if I messed up my description of the characters I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long and short of it is that, in a large number of collations, the characters in your first example are equal to a space.

When doing string comparisons, SQL server eliminates trailing spaces on the end of a string (one exception being when you use `LIKE`, but you're not doing that here).

So, for example, in the string `N'食料ㇰ ㇱ ㇲ ㇳ'`, every character after `料` is treated as a trailing space and removed when doing your string comparison.

To do a quick check with a given collation, you could run the following query:

```
WITH 
    Vals AS (SELECT FullString, StringNum FROM (VALUES (N'食料', 1), (N'食料ㇰ ㇱ ㇲ ㇳ', 2), (N'食料ク　シ　ス　ト', 3)) AS T(FullString, StringNum)),
    CTE AS -- A recursive CTE to split the characters up in your strings and check the individual characters. 
    (
        SELECT FullString,
                StringNum,
                IndividualCharacter = SUBSTRING(FullString, 1, 1),
                UnicodeNumber = UNICODE(SUBSTRING(FullString, 1, 1)),
                UnicodeBinary = CAST(SUBSTRING(FullString, 1, 1) AS VARBINARY(2)),
                CharPosition = 1
        FROM Vals
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT V.FullString,
                V.StringNum,
                IndividualCharacter = SUBSTRING(V.FullString, C.CharPosition + 1, 1),
                UnicodeNumber = UNICODE(SUBSTRING(V.FullString, C.CharPosition + 1, 1)),
                UnicodeBinary = CAST(SUBSTRING(V.FullString, C.CharPosition + 1, 1) AS VARBINARY(2)),
                CharPosition = C.CharPosition + 1
        FROM Vals AS V
        JOIN CTE AS C
            ON C.StringNum = V.StringNum
        WHERE C.CharPosition + 1 <= LEN(V.FullString)
    )
SELECT C.*,
       CharacterEqualToSpace = CASE WHEN NCHAR(C.UnicodeNumber) COLLATE Japanese_Unicode_CS_AS_KS_WS = NCHAR(32) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
       FullStringWithoutSpace = SUBSTRING(C.FullString, 1, (SELECT MAX(CharPosition) FROM CTE AS C2 WHERE C2.StringNum = C.StringNum AND NCHAR(C2.UnicodeNumber) COLLATE Japanese_Unicode_CS_AS_KS_WS != NCHAR(32))) -- Eliminate white space on the end for this collation, with a substring ending at the last character that does not equal white space.
FROM CTE AS C
ORDER BY StringNum, CharPosition;
```

From doing some quick tests...
 - Japanese collations that *will not* treat those specific characters as a space: Any BIN collation, Japanese_Bushu_Kakusu, Japanese_XJIS
 - Japanese collations that *will* treat those specific characters as a space: Japanese, Japanese90, Japanese_Unicode

Note: There are over 21000 characters in Japanese_Unicode_CS_AS_KS_WS that are treated as white space. You can check this by running a query like the following for a given collation:

```
WITH T(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) AS A(B)), -- 16
    T2(N) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 FROM T AS A CROSS JOIN T AS B CROSS JOIN T AS C CROSS JOIN T) -- 16^4.
SELECT WhiteSpaceCharacters = NCHAR(N)
FROM T2
WHERE NCHAR(N) COLLATE Japanese_Unicode_CS_AS_KS_WS = NCHAR(32);
```